# Everscale blockchain: dev wallet setup

Tags: everscale

I'm learning ton blockchain development, and I want to deploy the first contract to the **net.ton.dev**.

I follow this instruction
https://docs.ton.dev/86757ecb2/p/94921e-multisignature-wallet-management-in-tonos-cli/t/59b175

and there is an unclear step
"**3.4. Send tokens to the new address from another wallet**"

There is a question, how can I send tokens to the new address from another wallet if I don't have any wallets? How can I create that wallet?
It is a bit unclear how to pass this step?

I appreciate any help with this question.

Thank you

Comment: https://docs.everos.dev/everdev/guides/work-with-devnet#sponsor-giver-with-public-faucet

Answer (score 2):

You may use the telegram bot giver https://t.me/everdev_giver_bot

like `/give 100 0:xyz...`